# Published data updates child view but not parent view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have created this example that demonstrates the problem I'm running into with my app. I have a view with a property that a parent view and itself need to use to update the UI. What happens is that the child view updates when the property changes but the parent view does not.

What I'm trying to achieve with the code below is that when you tap on the text a blue outline appears if the state is true, otherwise there is no outline. What actually happens it that the child view updates (text changes) but the parent view remains the same (blue outline stays the same).

```
/********************Child View***************************/
class ExampleChildViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()
    @Published var showOptions: Bool
    
    init( _ show: Bool ) {
        showOptions = show
    }
}

struct ExampleChildView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: ExampleChildViewModel
    
    var body: some View{
        Text("\(String(model.showOptions))")
        .onTapGesture {
            self.model.showOptions.toggle()
        }
    }
}

/********************Parent View***************************/
class ExampleParentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var children = [ExampleChildViewModel]()
    
    init(){
        children.append( ExampleChildViewModel( true ) )
        children.append( ExampleChildViewModel( false ) )
    }
}

struct ExampleParentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var parent: ExampleParentViewModel
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            ForEach( parent.children, id: \.id ){ m in
                ExampleChildView( model: m )
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 30)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                            .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 3)
                            .opacity((m.showOptions) ? 1 : 0) // <---- Doesn't update
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

/********************Main View*******************************/
struct ExampleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = ExampleParentViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ExampleParentView( parent: model )
        }
    }
}
```

Why does `parent` in `ExampleParentView` not get updated when `showOptions` in `ExampleChildViewModel`is set?

Edit:

This is what the actual app is trying to show/hide. Each of the rows with the lock symbols are the child views.

[image: Showing the overlay that exists in the parent]

If I have the overlay in the child view I end up with the following

[image: Child overlay ends up behind other views]

Comment: I'm not very familiar with SwiftUI, but I think it's because `ExampleParentViewModel` `children` will only publish for shallow changes to the array itself, not deep changes to the objects it contains.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you want the Parent view to be responsible for managing the outline of each child view?  Seems like they should be determine their own layouts which you could do by moving the overlay into the child view:

```
struct ExampleChildView: View {

    @ObservedObject var model: ExampleChildViewModel
    
    var body: some View{
        HStack {
            Text("\(String(model.showOptions))")
        }
        .frame(width: 60, height: 30)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 3)
                .opacity((model.showOptions) ? 1 : 0))
        .onTapGesture {
            self.model.showOptions.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The overlay ends up being in the parent view as in reality it's a custom context menu that needs to overlay all other views. When it was in the child view it ended up under some other views in the parent. The parent ends up with N children, each of which I want to be able to show their context menu.

Comment: To get the context menu on top of all the over views, you could put it in a ZStack and change it's Z position.

Comment: Maybe it's silly but I'm stumped on how to change the z axis for things that are in a VStack. So imagine a VStack with 5 views in it, view number 3 & 4 are one of these child views where the overlay needs to be on top of view #3, 4, and 5. How do I keep them vertically aligned with each other and then move view 3 or view 4 to the top of the ZStack during runtime? is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit strange why you would define the look of a view in another view. Usually you do all the "tuning" in the View (this case the ChildView) itself and just implement it in the ParentView.

Now to the problem. `@Published` works like `@State`. When changed it notifies the view to update. And there lies your problem. It notifies the ChildView to update but not the ParentView. You can see this when modifying the ParentView as follows:

```
var body: some View{
    VStack{
        ForEach( self.parent.children, id: \.id ){ m in
            
            ExampleChildView( model: m )
                .opacity( m.showOptions ? 1 : 0)
                .frame(width: 60, height: 30)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 3)
                        .opacity( m.showOptions ? 1 : 0)// <---- Doesn't update
                )
        
        }
        

        
        Text("Current State?").onTapGesture {
            for m in self.parent.children {
                print(m.showOptions)
            }
            print("-----------")
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that the variables are changing but as your ParentView does not get notified to update it doesn't update.

The false/ true text does update as this gets defined in the ChildView. Implement the Overlay also in the ChildView and it works as you would expect it:

```
struct ExampleChildView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var model: ExampleChildViewModel
    
    var body: some View{
        Text("\(String(model.showOptions))")
            .onTapGesture {
                self.model.showOptions.toggle()
            }.overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                    .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 3)
                    .opacity( self.model.showOptions ? 1 : 0)
            )
    }
}
```

I'd suggest you to implement the entire, or at least the major (changing) part of the styling of a View in the View itself.

Also: This article explains it quite well
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/sharing-swiftui-state-with-observedobject

Comment: Yeah I suppose the example doesn't explain why it's setup this way. The overlay that occurs in the parent view is a custom context menu that should also be on top of every other view in the parent view. The outline is just a way to see the parent view state in the example.

Comment: Is there a way to "forward" the state notification from the child to the parent?